# Ruby on Rails, send multiple emails simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, in my RoR application I have a cinema system where users have preferences, which include saving their favourite actor. What I am trying to do is get it so that when a new film is added, if users have the any of film's actors saved as their favourite they will get an email notifying them of the film.

At the minute I can get it so that, through using a where statement, when a film is added the FIRST user in the array is emailed, films_controller:

```
def create
    @film = Film.new(film_params)
    if @film.save
        if not @film.cast1.blank?
            user1 = Perference.where(actor: @film.cast1).first.user
            if not user1.blank?
                actor = @film.cast1
                FavouriteActor.favourite_actor(user1, actor).deliver
            end
        end
        if not @film.cast2.blank?
            user2 = Perference.where(actor: @film.cast2).first.user
            if not user2.blank?
                actor = @film.cast2
                FavouriteActor.favourite_actor(user2, actor).deliver
            end
        end
        if not @film.cast3.blank?
            user3 = Perference.where(actor: @film.cast3).first.user
            if not user3.blank?
                actor = @film.cast3
                FavouriteActor.favourite_actor(user3, actor).deliver
            end
        end
        redirect_to @film
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

This then goes to the `favourite_actor.rb` mailer:

```
class FavouriteActor < ApplicationMailer
 def favourite_actor(user, actor)
    @user = user
    @actor = actor
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/films'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Your favourite actor stars in a new film')
 end
end
```

Which then sends the `favourite_actor.html.erb` email

But what can I do to replace this lines like: `user1 = Perference.where(actor: @film.cast1).first.user`so that all the users with that actor as their favourite are emailed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your queries a bit:

```
preferences = Preference.where(["actor = ? OR actor = ? OR actor = ?", @film.cast1, @film.cast2, @film.cast3]).includes(:user)

preferences.each do |preference|
  FavoriteActor.favourite_actor(preference.user, actor).deliver
end
```

Comment: And this would go in films_controller?

Comment: I get this error: `undefined method `include' for #<Perference::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x6c84a98>` and you've also got a random '[' in your first line

Comment: Oh! typo. Corrected it. It should be `includes`

Comment: I now get this error: `Association named 'users' was not found on Perference; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: I get the above error but have the correct associations between them

Comment: You need to write `user` instead of `users`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something like:

```
users = Preference.where(actor: @film.cast1)
users.each do |user|
  FavoriteActor.favourite_actor(user, actor).deliver
end
```

If I understand what you are wanting to do correctly, this will find all users with that favorite actor, iterate through the set and email each.

Comment: This will throw error, as you are passing preference obj as a first arg of `favourite_actor` method, which is expecting user obj